# How to count number of elements in a JSON array in Delphi

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, count

I am accessing a TJSONValue in Delphi(using REST components and Google Books' API). I want to know how many elements are in the array: 'items'.
This is the format of the JSONValue:

> ```
>    "kind": "books#volumes",
>    "totalItems": 221,
>    "items": [
>        {...},
>        {...},
>        {...}]
> ```

Note* "totalItems" does not refer to the size of the array.

I've tried somethin along this line, but it raises a conversion error.

```
var
   JSONBook: TJSONValue;
   CountItems: integer;
begin
   JSONBook := RESTResponse1.JSONValue;

   ShowMessage(IntToStr(JSONBook.GetValue<string>('items').Length));
   CountItems := JSONBook.GetValue<string>('items').Length;

   for i := 0 to CountItems-1 do
   begin
     ...
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Where does it raise the error message? What types are the variables you used?

Comment: At the showmessage. CountItems is an integer.

Comment: `CountItems` is not in ShowMessage.

Comment: `CountItems` is one line below the ShowMessage. There are no variables in the ShowMessage's parameters, save for `JSONBook` which is a TJSONValue as I stated.

Comment: What type does `JSONBook.GetValue<string>('items').Length` return?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know if the syntax is even correct. `JSONBook.GetValue<string>('items').Length` is supposed to return an integer value.

Comment: Since `items` is an array, not a string, trying to read it with `GetValue<string>` should raise an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `items` field is an array, so retrieving it as a `string` is just wrong, so it makes sense that reading the array count via a string length would not work.

Try this instead:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.JSON;

var
  JSONBook, JSONItem: TJSONObject;
  JSONItems: TJSONArray;
  CountItems: integer;
begin
  JSONBook := RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
  JSONItems := JSONBook.GetValue('items') as TJSONArray;

  CountItems := JSONItems.Count;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(CountItems));

  for i := 0 to CountItems-1 do
  begin
    JSONItem := JSONItems.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(140): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Get'. `JSONItems := JSONBook.Get('items') as TJSONArray;` is not working. Do I need to add something in `Uses`?

Comment: @Janrich do you have an online resource for this JSON so we can look? Because I don't know by heart the classes, `Get` is, generally, a method which, here, you don't have and I doubt that `JSONBook.GetValue<string>('items').Length;` returns `integer`.

Comment: @Janrich sorry my bad, `JSONBook.Get()` should be `JSONBook.GetValue()`, I have corrected it in my answer

Comment: Yes indeed! I checked but didn't find. What is the equivalent way with `TJSONIterator`? `Depth` maybe?

Comment: @LegitLearner "*What is the equivalent way with `TJSONIterator`?*" - The equivalent way of WHAT, exactly? To get the number of elements in the array? You can't get that from an iterator, without actually iterating through the array and counting the number of elements found. `Depth` is something else completely different.

Comment: Thanks @remy-lebeau, "The equivalent way of WHAT, exactly?" i meant how to count the number of elements.